# Crawling rules in heritrix, how to load embedded content?

Tags: heritrix

I want heritrix (version 3.4.0 currently) to crawl site.domain/path and load all pages below that but also include needed things to show the pages, like imgages, scripts and such.

According to https://heritrix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary.html heading "Discovery Path", what I want is "Embedded links" - E and maybe Speculative embed - X. I do not want it to follow normal links - L outside my path.

I have been experimenting with the rules and my basic idea is this: (Last matching rule wins according to docs.)

- accept all
- reject everything outside site.domain/path
- accept embedded files (images/css/script/etc)

It works fine to crawl, only pages within that path on the server but it does not load the needed files for the pages.

**How to make it load the needed files as well?**

Configuration in my job so far:

```
 <bean id="scope" class="org.archive.modules.deciderules.DecideRuleSequence">
  <property name="rules">
   <list>
     <bean class="org.archive.modules.deciderules.AcceptDecideRule" />
     <bean class="org.archive.modules.deciderules.NotMatchesListRegexDecideRule">
       <property name="decision" value="REJECT"/>
       <property name="regexList">
         <list>
           <value>.*site\.domain/path/.*</value>
         </list>
       </property>
    </bean>
     
    <!-- HOW to accept embedded things here? -->
     
     <!-- Below are some of the "standard" rules set up on a fresh job, it behaves the same with and without them when it comes to not loading embedded stuff -->
    <bean class="org.archive.modules.deciderules.TooManyHopsDecideRule">
     <!-- <property name="maxHops" value="20" /> -->
    </bean>
    <!-- ...and REJECT those with suspicious repeating path-segments... -->
    <bean class="org.archive.modules.deciderules.PathologicalPathDecideRule">
     <!-- <property name="maxRepetitions" value="2" /> -->
    </bean>
    <!-- ...and REJECT those with more than threshold number of path-segments... -->
    <bean class="org.archive.modules.deciderules.TooManyPathSegmentsDecideRule">
     <!-- <property name="maxPathDepth" value="20" /> -->
    </bean>
    <!-- ...but always ACCEPT those marked as prerequisitee for another URI... -->
    <bean class="org.archive.modules.deciderules.PrerequisiteAcceptDecideRule">
    </bean>
    <!-- ...but always REJECT those with unsupported URI schemes -->
    <bean class="org.archive.modules.deciderules.SchemeNotInSetDecideRule">
    </bean>
    
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

Comment: Oh... now I found that HopsPathMatchesRegexDecideRule maybe does what I want...

Answer (score 0):

This accepts those containing E or X in the Discovery Path.

```
    <bean class="org.archive.modules.deciderules.HopsPathMatchesRegexDecideRule">
      <property name="decision" value="ACCEPT"/>
      <property name="regex" value="(E|X)$" />
    </bean>
```

PS
Ironic when you spend some hours on something and when you make a question and while making an adjustment on it stumble upon the solution.

UPDATE: Added a $-sign at the end of the regular expression as it might find other things and continue the crawl anyway.